Visualizing $\mathbb{R}^3 / S^1 \times S^1$ ($\mathbb{R}^3$ with the torus collapsed to a point)
I've been working through exercises to improve my ability to visualize different quotient spaces because I'm quite horrible at it (thanks, aphantasia), and I'm stuck with how to correctly interpret/describe this space.
Some similar-ish quotient spaces that I think are correct:

$\mathbb{R}^2$ with the circle $S^1$ collapsed to a point: this will be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $S^2$ (a sphere) attached at the center of the circle.
$\mathbb{R}^2$ with an annulus $A$ (say, centered at the origin) collapsed to a point: homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $S^2$ attached to the origin. Correction: This should be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $S^2$ attached.

Based on these, if we take the torus to be 'centered' at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, my best guess is that this will similarly be $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $S^2$ centered at the origin, but I'm uncertain about whether this is a correct interpretation of this space.
I'd be grateful for any guidance on how to think about this space. Also, any references with explicit examples on how to visualize similar quotient spaces would be immensely helpful!

Why would a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by an annulus be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an attached sphere?

@NaïmFavier oops, I think I see a mistake. This should be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an attached sphere, which would make sense I guess because the annulus is homotopy equivalent to the circle.

You should adjust your best guess too: There's no reason to expect $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be involved (the space looks just like ordinary $\mathbb{R}^3$ away from the origin where all the action happens).

In any case your guess is wrong: You can think of the setting as being given two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely $X = \tilde{T}^2$, the "filled" torus, and $Y = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \operatorname{int} X$ the complement of its interior. Then $X \cap Y = T^2$, the usual 2-dim. torus, and you should expect the quotient to be homeomorphic to $X / T^2 \vee Y / T^2$, where $\vee$ denotes the wedge sum. But $X / T^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^3 \wedge S^2$, so you at least have copy of $S^3$. What $Y / T^2$ is I don't see directly.

I should probably point out that it's not at all glaringly obvious that $X / T^2$ is of that form, so you shouldn't worry if you can't see it :) I'm using a trick here (namely that $X$ can be identified with the disk bundle of the trivial rank 2 real vector bundle over $S^1$, so that $X / T^2$ is precisely its Thom space, and that the Thom space of a trivial bundle over $X$ is a suspension of $X_+$), but if you know some algebraic topology you can relatively quickly verify if a guess is plausible by computing homology.

Oh, that's an interesting trick! Thank you so much for the clarification and insight!

Hi @BenSteffan, are you sure $X/T^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^3 \wedge S^2$? IDK what a Thom space is, but if you meant "$S^3$ smash-product $S^2$" (AKA $S^5$) then that seems to be too high-dimensional to be the right answer, but if you meant "$S^3$ wedge-sum $S^2$" then I think it seems to be too low-dimensional in the $S^2$ part (and it has a cut point, which seems fishy). It seems to me that $X/T^2$ will be the one-point compactification of the open filled torus, which is homeomorphic to $S^3 \setminus S^1$, so it will be the weird space $S^3/S^1$.

@IzaakvanDongen I meant to type $S^3 \vee S^2$ but got caught in the the \wedge trap... I agree that it's the compactification of the open filled torus. As for it's relation to $S^3 \setminus S^1$, I'm not sure, but if you look at the accepted answer to the question you link, you see that the homology groups of $S^3 / S^1$ agree with those of $S^3 \vee S^2$, so maybe this latter space is not as weird as you think ;)

On the other hand, existence of "cut point" is a fair argument, so perhaps I have accidentally (and incorrectly) strengthened a homotopy equivalence to a homeomorphism somewhere.
